# Anydesk: Black screen issue

Tags: remote-access, anydesk

I am facing one weird issue since yesterday. As and when I am trying to connect to remote machine, I am getting this black screen. Not sure why is it happening.

[image: Anydesk Screenshot]

Any help would be great.

Comment: Also asked [here](https://superuser.com/q/1498176/810934)

Comment: Are you using Wayland session?

Answer (score 1):

**Black Screen Issue in Linux/ Ubuntu**

1. Wayland is not supported by Anydesk;
2. Check `Gnome Desktop Manager` configuration:

```bash
cat /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

3. Check if there is an entry:

```bash
WaylandEnable=true
```

4. Edit the configuration file;

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

5. Set `WaylandEnable` to `false`;

```bash
WaylandEnable=false
```

6. Inside `nano` text editor, Press `CTRL+X` and save the configuration file;
7. Restart your computer;
8. Enjoy Anydesk with a colorful screen!